# Is it possible to rename a GitHub SSH key?

Tags: github, ssh

The following question concerns the `SSH and GPG keys` section of GitHub's `Personal settings` area (see screen cap below).

[image: The SSH and GPG keys section of the Personal settings area]

Once a new SSH key has been added, is it possible to rename it (i.e. to give it a new Title) either explicitly or by deleting the existing key and then adding a new one with a different Title but with the same Key?

Please answer the above in two cases: (1) the key has never been used to access a repository of the account, (2) the key has been used to access a repository of the account.

---

**Background** Today I deleted a SSH entry and then tried to add it again with a different title, but GitHub refused to add it, emitting the following message: `Key is already in use`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not possible to rename keys on GitHub. You can only delete them.

[image]

But it is possible to delete them and add them with a new name. It doesn't matter for this whether or not it has been used already.

Be careful: When you delete the key, it is not possible to restore it. To add it again, you need to have access to the public key.

Comment: Thanks. So what am I doing wrong? Today I deleted a SSH entry and then tried to add it again with a different title, but GitHub refused to add it, emitting the following message: `Key is already in use`.

Comment: Check this help article by GitHub to find out where the key is used: https://help.github.com/articles/error-key-already-in-use/

Comment: Thanks. So why does your answer state that "It doesn't matter for this whether or not it has been used already"?

Comment: Because I misunderstood your question. Check my screenshot, I thought you were referencing the "Last used within the last 3 months". Your issue is not so much whether or not a key has been used to *access a repository*, but that it is configured as a deployment key somewhere. That is a totally different issue.

Comment: I tried to follow the instructions in the article you linked to above. It did not go as smoothly as in the article. Instead, the terminal asked me to enter a passphrase for the key. I have no idea what passphrase I'm supposed to enter. Do you have a clue? Is it the passphrase for logging in to GitHub? Is it the passphrase for logging in to my computer?

Comment: It is the passphrase for the SSH key. The private part of a SSH key can be protected with a passphrase, which is what the terminal asks for. Otherwise, it can't decrypt the private key and use it to connect you with GitHub.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139992/discussion-between-jdno-and-evan-aad).